# JHipster - Elasticsearch examples for search field

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

Having an example entity like

```
entity Vehicle {
id                 Long,
manufacturer       String,
model              String
}
```

and using ElasticSearch, how do queries in the search input field have to look like in the front end provided by the JHipster application?

A search might involve only one column or a combination of the given columns.

Let's say:

```
id = 1
manufacturer = Ferrari
manufacturer = Ferrari AND model = Model 1
```

or involving other query keywords like LIKE, etc.

How to specify those queries into the search input field?